# javascript get element by id vs object id

Tags: javascript

why do you have to use getObjectById, if you already know the ID of an object?  It keeps on throwing me off, because I replace it with the ID of the element that I am referring to.

EDIT:
I think i may have just forgotten the #.  But why does getObjectById exist, if you can assign an element an ID?

Comment: What is `getObjectById`? Can you show a code sample of what's throwing you off?

Comment: Post relevant code here and be more specific.

Comment: You will have to post the code you're talking about for us to know how to advise you.  Your question is unclear and requires seeing your code.

Comment: Do you want to know what the use of `getElementById` ?

Comment: yes i would like to know that

Answer (score 0):

To apply some action on any element at first you have to tell the javascript the identification of that element, say you want to add an event listener on a specific element and to do that you have to do (short exemple)

```
​<div id="myDiv">​Some Text</div>​

document.getElementById('myDiv').onclick=function(){
    alert('clicked on div !');
}
```

Above code `document.getElementById('myDiv').onclick=function(){...}` tells javascript to execute the function (right after=) when someone clicks on the div which has the id `myDiv`.

**Actually returns a reference to the element by its ID.**

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/g2wKz/1/)

**Reference:** [**Here.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)